# Puppet and realize virtual resources

Tags: linux, puppet

i'working on a puppetmodule for mongodb

Here is what I have (stripped down to the basics):

modules/mongodb/manifests/virtual.pp:

```
class mongodb::virtual {

  @package {['mongo-10gen-server','mongo-10gen']:
    ensure => installed
  }
```

modules/mongodb/manifests/replicaset.pp:

```
define mongodb::replicaset {
  realize( Package['mongo-10gen-server','mongo-10gen'] )
}
```

quite simple, but when I do a puppetrun on the client:

```
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/custom_facts.rb
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to realize virtual resources Package[mongo-10gen-server], Package[mongo-10gen] on node mongonode
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Any idea whats wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1):

Have to answer my own question :S

It was a typical layer8 error:
I forgot to include the ::virtual class in replicaset.pp